# How to display glyphicon icon in the same line as subsequent text

Tags: css, glyphicons

HTML:

```
<ul>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> this is the line 1<br>    
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> this is the line 2<br>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>  this is the line 3
</ul>
```

Page displays icon and text in two different lines.
[image] I inspected in chrome browser and put *display:inline* for glyphicon class, it worked in browser. But When I put the code in css file, it does not overwrite. How can I put texts and icon on same line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is invalid HTML - inside of a ul element you need to use li elements (which makes the `br` tags superfluous). Plus change `display` of the `.glyphicon` class to `inline`, since you say it doesn't overwrite it properly, add `!important`:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.glyphicon {
  display: inline !important;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> this is the line 1</li>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> this is the line 2</li>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> this is the line 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

First clear your browser cache then why don't you change

```
.glyphicon {
  display: block
}
```

to

```
.glyphicon {
 display:inline
}
```

on line 386 line of your css file ?

Second way and easiest try this

```
.glyphicon {
   display:inline !important
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To overwrite that rule, consider adding more *specificity* to the selectors.

**Selector Specificity:**

Add another `class` selector to the range of selectors...

```
.glyphicon.glyphicon-ok {
   display: block;
}
```

or an element selector...

```
span.glyphicon {
   display: block;
}
```

*contextual selectors* will also over-qualify a single class selector declaration

```
ul .glyphicon {
   display: block;
}
```

All the aforementioned declarations carry more specificity than a single class selector declaration like:

```
.glyphicon {
   display: block;
}
```

**Specificity & Weight:**

> Specificity is a weight that is applied to a given CSS declaration,
>   determined by the number of each selector type in the matching
>   selector. When multiple declarations have equal specificity, the last
>   declaration found in the CSS is applied to the element. Specificity
>   only applies when the same element is targeted by multiple
>   declarations.

Ref: [Specificity - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

**The Cascade Precedence:**

If two rules carry equal weight and/or specificity, the one declared last wins and will *overqualify* the other. CSS embedded in the html always come after external stylesheets regardless of the order in the html.

*You are trying to overqualify a style rule, with the same specificity, that is declared after your custom rule.*

The style rule in question is declared internally (within the document, `(index:386)`) and therefore declared *last* and *lower down* in the *cascade order* than the custom style rule declared externally (within an external stylesheet, `css_injector_3.css`).

`style.css` <sup>**1**</sup> **<** `<style></style>` <sup>**2**</sup> **<** `style=""` <sup>**3**</sup>

1. *External styles* - style declared through an external source, like a
   `.css` source file
2. *Internal styles* - styles declared within `style` element tags
   (contained within the html document)
3. *Inline styles* - styles declared directly to the element through
   `style` attribute values

Your rules may have initially worked when declaring them in browser if they where declared either by:

1. *Inline* - css applied directly to the element using the `style` attribute.
2. *Inspector Stylesheet* - new rules declared after any standard rules